# xcode 3.2 c++: how can i enable a proper code completion?

Tags: xcode, code-completion

I have snow leopard and I'm building a cpp Application with xcode.

I would like to be able to get proper code completion with xcode, and by that i mean the following:

```
std::string f;
f.
```

just when I type `f.` i would like to see all the relevant functions to that string class. is it possible in xcode ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to press the ESC key to get the code completion menu to show.

Answer (score 1):

It may seem counterintuitive but press the ESC key after the period.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the completion menu to display automatically, you can also set that in your preferences:

**Code Sense -> Code Completion -> Automatically Suggest**